# How to pre-select a value in angular2 material design drop down?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to pre-select a value in dropdowns of angular2 material design. I have done the following but that's not working

```
<label *ngFor="let service of serviceOptions">
    <b>{{service.serviceName}}</b>
    <br /><br />

      <md-select placeholder="Select Package" [(ngModel)]="service.selectedPackage" formControlName="packageName" size="30">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let package of (reactivePackages | async)"  >
          <md-option *ngIf="service.serviceId==package.serviceId" (click)="selectServicePackage(service, package)">
            {{ package.packageName}}
          </md-option>
        </ng-container>
      </md-select>
    <br />  <br />
  </label>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `value` property binding inside `<md-option>` to assign the selected value to `service.selectedPackage`. Since you have `[(ngModel)]="service.selectedPackage"`, its value should match with the binding property of `package`.

Here's example of binding `md-option` to `package.packageName` assuming `service.selectedPackage` holds similar values.

```
<md-option [value]="package.packageName" 
           *ngIf="service.serviceId==package.serviceId" 
           (click)="selectServicePackage(service, package)">
  {{ package.packageName}}
</md-option>
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ind0oyQOdiNkbW96m8ID?p=preview)

Comment: my values are coming from an http request. That's why I have applied the ascync pipe. Even after adding [value] property it's still not working because of async probably. Any idea?